# How to change Ubuntu boot manager on dual boot?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I am having both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows7 in my system. The problem is when it is booting the boot options very ugly and it shows 6 options. But there are only two options only for both of the operating systems. How to change the boot manager like I want better environment for booting? Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) and hide some of your boot options, if you want.

Use with caution! Be careful not to delete anything that you shouldn't and mess up your grub configuration, as you'll end up with an unbootable system.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend manually editing a simple text file instead of using a third-party program to modify an important system file although my recommend requires the user to be very careful.

All you need to do in this case is to open the file **grub.cfg** with admin rights, for example entering this command in a terminal window:

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

This file includes all grub menu items starting with the term "**menuentry**" and ending with culry brackets **}**
You can then carefully edit and/or remove each such menu item and then saving and exiting to restart with a customized grub menu (which will be overwritten after every kernel upgrade)